# Newline state after reading a line with a prompt seems not be updated

Tags: common-lisp, newline, clisp

I am using GNU CLISP and getting crazy because this program:

```
(read-line)
(format t "~&<prompt RESPONSE")
```

Outputs something like:

```
my input...
<prompt RESPONSE
```

But if I print a prompt before (read-line) I get a spurious empty line:

```
(format t "~&prompt> ")
(read-line)
(format t "~&<prompt RESPONSE")
```

E.g.:

```
prompt> my input...

<prompt RESPONSE
```

I have tried using (finish-output) both before and after read-line, but it didn't help. I do not understand where that empty line come from. I suspect there is a bug in CLISP.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem under Linux Mint (Debian derivative). Are you using CLISP under Windows?

Comment: Thank you for asking this! I'd been meaning to type up a similar question... Specifically asking if there was a way to make the conditional newline aware of user input, because other scenarios can also make this Not What's Wanted...

Comment: @lindes I could imagine a scenario where you don't know in advance whether the user's input ends with a newline, namely in situations where you're accepting one keystroke at a time. The REPL doesn't work that way. It accepts one line of user input at a time, always ending in a newline. Side note: If you enter more than one expression at a time (i.e., enter them all on one line) in the REPL, the output gets mixed up, so I suggest not doing that.

Comment: Well, in the case of the repl then, if input always ends with a newline, then it seems to me that the output state ought well to be updated by input... Unless, say, you've turned off "echo" on your pseudo-terminal (say, for entering a password or something)... No?? Am I explaining myself well?

Answer (score 2):

For those who don't know, `~&` in a `format` command is a conditional newline, which means "print a newline if need be". That is, only print a newline if the last thing lisp printed wasn't already a newline.

The `format` function (at least on your machine!) ignores user input when deciding whether to issue a newline. This may not be the case on all systems. I really don't remember.

Let's focus on the `~&` that immediately precedes `<prompt RESPONSE`. In your first case, `format` sees that it hasn't printed anything yet and thus does not need to print a newline. In the second case `format` sees that the last thing it printed was not a newline and therefore it needs to print a newline.

The solution: Knowing that the user will always provide the newline, don't include it in your `format` statement. You can even remove it from your initial prompt if you wish:

```
(format t "prompt> ")
(read-line)
(format t "<prompt RESPONSE")
```

So, then the question arises, "Then what is `~&` for anyhow?" And, indeed, there are other uses for it. For example, to separate 2 consecutive lines of output:

```
(format t "prompt> ")
(read-line)
(format t "<prompt RESPONSE 1~&<prompt RESPONSE 2")
```

Comment: The question I'm left with is whether this can be made to be aware of the input content. Can it? If so, how?

Comment: What do you want to do with the input? Store it in a variable?

Comment: @lindes I just read your other comment, which answers my previous comment.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply. My problem is actually that (format t "~&<prompt RESPONSE") is found in another function that gets called from different places and in some cases I do need to print a newline before the prompt. This is why I cannot just omit the ~&, because in other cases I need it. Of course I can print the newline where needed before calling the function, but it gets clumsy. What I really wanted is the function to the take care of this automatically when needed. Do you think I should send a bug report to the CLISP developers?

Comment: @AntonioBonifati I'm sorry Lisp isn't more accommodating. The same thing unfortunately happens in (at least some) other Lisps too. I doubt the CLISP developers or any other Lisp developers would consider it their bug. They would tell you to reorganize your code so that it doesn't happen. Such a workaround probably means moving the `~&` to the end of some other `format` strings. :-(